# Creating a packed version of a template class in C++14

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, packed

I would like to make an `__attribute__((packed))` version of a template class, to use it in packed structs to send or receive as bytes. But I don't want the cost of packed to impact the arithmetic and other aspects on the regular use of the class (compiling for ARM using GCC with c++14).

So I have a template class like this example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Vec3 {
    T x, y, z;

    constexpr Vec3() = default;
    constexpr Vec3(T x, T y, T z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    constexpr Vec3& operator=(const Vec3& v);

    constexpr Vec3 operator+(const Vec3& v) const;

    template<typename U>
    constexpr auto operator+(const Vec3<U>& v) const -> Vec3<decltype(T{} + U{})>;

    // many other member functions
}

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto dot(const Vec3<T>& v1, const Vec3<U>& v2) -> decltype(T{} * U{});

// other non-member functions
```

Now I would like to make a packed version of the Vec3 class, something like:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class PackedType;

template<typename T>
using Packed = std::conditional_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T, PackedType<T>>;

template<typename T>
struct __attribute__((packed)) PackedType<Vec3<T>> {
    Packed<T> x, y, z; // make sure the internal type is packable

    constexpr PackedType(const Vec3<T>& v) : x(v.x), y(v.y), z(v.z) {}

    constexpr operator Vec3<T>() const { return Vec3<T>(T(x), T(y), T(z)); }
}
```

But this is where it breaks down. The call to function expecting `Vec3` use template argument deduction/substitution, but `PackedType<Vec3<T>>` isn't a `Vec3`, nor is it derived from `Vec3`. So the compiler cannot deduce anything.

We would like the packed `Vec3` class to be converted to a regular `Vec3` when used in functions. As I said previously, we don't want/need operation to be performed on the packed values, so making a copy is fine.

But now we need to provide overload for all functions to use the packed version of the class, plus all the (regular, packed), (packed, regular), (packed, packed) for function with two arguments and so on... And I don't mean just the Vec3.h/cpp file, any function that as a templated `Vec3<T>` as argument might need to be overloaded.

As for the other options:

- The packed `Vec3` class cannot be derived from `Vec3` since regular `Vec3` isn't packed (my version of GCC does not raise an error on that one even though it is probably undefined behavior).
- Making a `template<typename T, bool Packed> struct Vec3 {}` and a specialization for packed and non-packed doesn't solve the issue of having to duplicate everything.
- Using explicitly a `v.unpack()` every time we need to make a conversion (and cry at the compiler output if you forget one)

To be clear, what I would like is a way to convert automatically a packed class into a regular class, the same way a c array decay into a pointer for example.

Comment: nitpick: Its not a template class, but a class template. A class template is not a class, it is a template.

Comment: "The call to function expecting Vec3 use template argument deduction/substitution..." what functions? THe issue is in those functions expecting a `Vec3` when you actually want them to accept anything that can be converted to a `Vec3`. Can you modify those functions?

Comment: ...or perhaps you want the functions to accept anything that has `x`,`y` and `z` members?

Comment: oh sorry there is an example already included: `dot`

Comment: In that case, I have control over the classes and functions. But I was also thinking on how a library would implement it, or for a library. Changing the function declaration is possible but the problem remain that type template deduction cannot happen if the type is different as far as I know.

Comment: my point was to write a `dot(const T& t, const U& u)`, then there is no "different type" and decution always works. Then you can add constraints via SFINAE, eg "T and U must be convertible to `Vec<T>`, then you can convert, whatever `t` and `u` is to `Vec<T>`s. I was actually about to write an answer, but I missed the c++14 tag and i ended up in a mess

Comment: while that does seem to work, the catch all does make it harder to see other problems in compiler errors, especially for constructors and operator overloading. (currently trying to implement it with generic template and SFINAE.)

Comment: if possible by any means you should try to get a more recent compiler where you can use c++20

Comment: I would love to but unfortunately not possible. Also, forget what I said about compiler errors with more generic templates, it always give me overloads with completely unrelated types ether way. The compiler is trying too hard but has no idea what is going on. The best is to trying to match as much as possible and `static_assert` the actual problem. No always possible tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065621/creating-a-packed-version-of-a-template-class-in-c14/77068153#comment135859493_77065621) does the trick.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Vec3 {
    using type = T;
    T x, y, z;
    //...
}

template<typename T>
struct isVec3Conv : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct isVec3Conv<Vec3<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct isVec3Conv<PackedType<Vec3<T>>> : std::true_type {};


template<typename V1, typename V2,
    std::enable_if_t<isVec3Conv<V1>::value && isVec3Conv<V2>::value, bool> = 0>
constexpr auto dot(const V1& v1, const V2& v2) ->
    decltype(typename V1::type{} * typename V2::type{});
```

In that case we can replace `typename V1::type{}` by `v1.x`, but my classes have more template type parameters and so my implementation become a bit longer because of that.